# Is there a way to force execution of import.sql before Quarkus Tests?

Tags: quarkus

I'd like to use for my Quarkus tests the H2 Test Resource:

```
@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)
```

However I need to have some tables available in the Database.
Although I have placed a resources/import.sql with the DDL in it, the test fails because it attempts to use tables from the configuration before executing the import.sql:

```
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.sql=SELECT u.password, u.role FROM test_user u WHERE u.username=?
```

As a result:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "TEST_USER" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT u.password, u.role FROM test_user u WHERE u.username=? [42102-197]
```

Any way to execute the SQL before Quarkus reads the configuration file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include into the JDBC Connection String the INIT Parameter with in it a reference to the SQL Script to execute. Example:

```
quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:elytron_jdbc_test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:import.sql'
```

See an example application which secures [Quarkus with H2 Database](http://www.mastertheboss.com/soa-cloud/quarkus/securing-quarkus-with-elytron-database-realm).

Answer (score 1):

You are now able to also add in the property `quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script`. Example:

```
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script=META-INF/sql/import-test.sql
```